# Why doesn't MySQL coerce the collation to the column-specified, when comparing to a literal?

Tags: mysql, collation, character-set

I have a table with a collation defined on a column:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test_table (
  utf8_col VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('ã');
```

According to the MySQL [coercibility rules](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collation-coercibility.html), when a value from that column is compared to a literal:

```sql
SELECT utf8_col < _utf8mb4'ñ' FROM test_table;
```

- the column collation coercibility value is 2;
- the literal CCV is 4

this should cause the comparison to fail, because the column CCV has higher priority, and should use the `utf8_bin` collation, which can't handle `utf8mb4` character sets.

The comparison is successful, however. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the above comparison succeed?

Because MySQL is being nice and auto-correcting a user error, but only because it can.

You are not wrong that:

1. > the column CCV has higher priority

and:

2. > the utf8_bin collation can't handle utf8mb4 character sets.

However, you are not seeing what you think you are seeing in your test because you are not testing with data that *requires* the "mb4" version of the "utf8" collations. You are testing with a "safe" value that fits into the non-supplementary character-capable `utf8` charset. In this situation, MySQL simply uses the charset of the column — `utf8` — and the `utf8_bin` collation is just fine.

The world looks a little different when you use a 4 byte character (i.e. a supplementary character). In this case, the character cannot exist in the `utf8` charset (because the `utf8` charset can only handle BMP characters / the first 65,536 code points / U+0000 through U+FFFF / characters that are 1 to 3 bytes each). And so, since the charset of the string literal cannot be changed to the one that does work with the column's collation — `utf8_bin` — you would get an error stating:

> Illegal mix of collations (utf8_bin,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '<'

I tested with code point U+1F369 (i.e. the donut emoji: "🍩"):

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  utf8_col VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
);

INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('ã'); # any utf8 character from U+0000 to U+FFFF

# Test against any utf8 character from U+0000 to U+FFFF in _utf8mb4
SELECT utf8_col,
       CHARSET(utf8_col) AS 'charset',
       COLLATION(utf8_col) AS 'collation',
       CONCAT(utf8_col, _utf8mb4'ñ') AS 'concat1',
       CHARSET(CONCAT(utf8_col, _utf8mb4'ñ')) AS 'charset_concat1'
FROM test_table;

# Test against any utf8 character from U+10000 to U+10FFFF in _utf8mb4
SELECT utf8_col,
       CHARSET(utf8_col) AS 'charset',
       COLLATION(utf8_col) AS 'collation',
       CONCAT(utf8_col, _utf8mb4'') AS 'concat2',
       CHARSET(CONCAT(utf8_col, _utf8mb4'')) AS 'charset_concat2'
FROM test_table;
# FAIL

SELECT utf8_col < _utf8mb4'ñ' FROM test_table; # Success


SELECT utf8_col < _utf8mb4'' FROM test_table; # FAIL
```

See the above example code [in action on dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4e371f1bf9431c2085fb606151b6a1ee)

The result set from the first `SELECT` is:

```
utf8_col    charset    collation    concat1    charset_concat1
ã           utf8       utf8_bin     ãñ         utf8
```

which shows that the `utf8mb4` string was coerced into `utf8`, and everyone was happy. *Was* happy, until Mr Donut showed up in the second `SELECT` statement (you would think that donuts would make everything better, though, wouldn't you? I generally do 😸).